# Get the main array index

Tags: php, arrays

```
$myArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => 87
            [2] => 76
            [3] => 37
            [4] => 69
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 56
            [3] => 26
            [4] => 60
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 29
            [2] => 59
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 65
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 29
            [3] => 59
            [4] => 28
        )
)
```

I have $myArray.
I want to get the main array index for a specified number.

E.g.:
If the number is 37, I want to get 0.
If the number is 56, I want to get 1.
If the number is 69, I want to get 0.
If the number is 28, I want to get 3.

I tried using the following function, but I get 0. Maybe there's an error?!?

```
function search2dArray($needle, $haystack) {
    if (is_array($haystack)) {
        for ($h = 0; $h < count($haystack); $h++) {
            $arraySearch = array_keys($haystack[$h], $needle);
            if ($arraySearch != 0) {
                return $h;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

echo search2dArray(60, $myArray);
```

Please can you help me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$myArray = array(
    array(27, 87, 76, 37, 69),
    array(2, 43, 56, 26, 60),
    array(36, 29, 59, 13, 65),
    array(63, 26, 29, 59, 28),
);

function search2dArray($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $subarray) {
        if (in_array($needle, $subarray))
            return $key;
    }
}

echo search2dArray(60, $myArray); //1
```

This should do it: loop over the array and check if the `$needle` is in one of the subarrays.

Answer (score 0):

array_keys() always reutrn array type,that's mean $arraySearch maybe is `array(4=>60);` OR empty array `array()`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the main array index for all subarray elements that equal an interger, you'll need to do something like this:

```
    <?php
$myArray = array(
array(27, 87, 76, 37, 69),
array(2, 43, 56, 26, 60),
array(36, 29, 59, 13, 65),
array(63, 26, 29, 59, 28),
);

function search2dArray($needle, $haystack) {
 $results_arr = array();
 foreach ($haystack as $key => $subarray) {
    if (in_array($needle, $subarray))
        array_push($results_arr, $key);
}
   echo $needle,' was found in<br />';

  foreach ($results_arr as $r_key => $master_index ){
        echo '$myArray['.$master_index.']<br />' ;
  }


  }

search2dArray(29, $myArray); //1

?>
```

OUTPUT:

29 was found in
   $myArray[2]
   $myArray[3]